# What is the physical meaning to the condition maximum efficiency in transformer?

Tags: transformer, efficiency

Mathematically I can see that When **Iron Loss = Copper loss** there is maximum efficiency, But why is this true? As far as I know Iron losses are completely independent quantities, So I can't understand this condition intuitively. Please help.

Comment: Power In = Power Out + losses…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a transformer is power throughput.

Power = volts x amps. You can get the same power with 100 V and 1 A, as with 10 V and 10 Amps, and 1 V and 100 A.

In a transformer, in a sense, the copper area is responsible for the current carrying. The iron area is responsible for the voltage handling.

You can build a transformer with a huge area iron core, which would therefore have a very large volts per turn, meaning that you needed little copper to achieve your power throughput. The resulting large volume iron core would lose a lot of power in hysteresis losses, assuming magnetisation to its maximum permitted flux. With few copper turns, there would be little copper loss.

Alternatively you could build a transformer with a small core, which would then need many turns of thin copper wire. At the same magnetisation flux, iron losses would be low, and copper losses high.

As the total loss is the sum of the two losses, but the power throughput is the product of their capabilities, either design could be improved by reducing the amount of high loss material, with a small increase in the amount of low loss material. If this isn't self evident, then I'll dig out a graph of a hyperbola.

Whether you get the best efficiency when both are exactly equal is another matter. There is certainly little point in reducing one loss a little at the cost of having the other loss increase by a lot. The optimum will tend to be around the equal contributions state.

'Efficient' is one of those words that means different things to different people. Many mean the ratio of power out to power in. However, manufacturers may well optimise their transformer for materials cost, rather than power cost. They may well use more (cheaper) iron for the core to save on (expensive) copper, with a resultant unbalancing of the losses.

There are two typical regimes for transformers; ones that operate at full power all the time, and ones that operate over a wide range of loads and may spend a lot of time at no load. These two regimes will use different optimisations for materials, as the full iron loss is present whenever voltage is applied, but copper loss only occurs when the transformer is on load. Transformers will therefore have equal losses only at some specific load.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency is a mathematical concept, so maximum efficiency doesn't really have a "physical meaning." Efficiency is an indication of resource optimization. You might say that waste is minimized when efficiency is maximized. However, you also need to consider load variation is a normal condition for the operation of many systems. That means that they can not always operated at the point of maximum efficiency. That means that the optimum design strategy may be to select a transformer that has a peak efficiency in the middle of the normal range of load variation.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that losses in a transformer can be minimized when copper losses equal core losses is only a design rule and not generally true. You are probably referring to a graph like this:
[image]

<sub>Source: Transformer and Inductors for Power Electronics (Hurley, Wölfle)</sub>

Core losses generally increase with flux density. You could look into core material datasheets, Steinmetz's equation or magnetic hysteresis for better understanding.

Copper losses on the other hand don't generally decrease with increasing flux density as the graph might suggest. Rather look at it in this way: higher flux density in a transformer can be achieved either by reducing the magnetizing inductance (e.g. number of turns) or by using a smaller magnetic core size. In both cases you can use shorter wires and thus reduce the winding resistance and copper losses.

There is a minimum in the overall losses somewhere in the middle of the road and this could be a starting point for a transformer design.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked myself this many times, but I've never paid much attention to the topic. In fact, I always thought that this was not related to the "Maximum Power Transfer Theorem". Apparently ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20electrical%20engineering%2C%20the%20maximum,viewed%20from%20its%20output%20terminals.) said this too), there is really no connection. It's just an interesting feature, as @Neil_UK described in his answer.